# Add an image source to ContentControl from C# code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, contentcontrol

I am trying to add a `ContentControl` through background code in C#, but failed to put image into `ContentControl` through code.

Here is the working code in Xaml

```
<ContentControl x:Name="cControl" Width="200"
              Height="200"
              Canvas.Left="210"
              Canvas.Top="220"
              Style="{StaticResource DesignerItemStyle}">
      <Image IsHitTestVisible="False" Stretch="Fill" Source="pack://application:,,,../Resources/ACImages/737.png"/>
</ContentControl>
```

in C# this is so far what I have:

```
 Image ACimage = new Image();
 BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
 image.BeginInit();
 image.UriSource = new Uri("pack://application:,,,../Resources/ACImages/737.png");
 image.EndInit();
 ACimage.Source = image;

 ContentControl myContentControl = new ContentControl();
 Style s = this.FindResource("DesignerItemStyle") as Style;
 myContentControl.Style = s;
```

How do I put the `ACimage` into the `ContentControl`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
myContentControl.Content=ACimage;
```